# Create jpanel in actionperformed listener?

Tags: java, swing, listener

I have 1 JFrame and 10 JPanel components as seperate classes. There is also JMenuBar on jframe. When a menu item clicked, i remove all content of contentPane of jframe (removeAll) and add one of my jpanels.

Here is my code;

```
// this function changes panel
public static void SwitchPanel(Component comp)
{
    Container panel = getContentPane();
    panel.removeAll();

    panel.add(comp);
    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
}

// this function defines menu items and their listeners
public JMenuItem AddMenuItem(JMenu menu, String name, final JPanel toPanel) {
    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(name);
    menu.add(menuItem);

    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            SwitchPanel(toPanel);
        }
    });

    return menuItem;
}
```

and i add menu items like that;

```
AddMenuItem(menu1, "some menu item", new MyPersonalJPanel());
```

Everything works. BUT i want to create new jpanel when a related menu item clicked. I mean create jpanel if only it is necessary. Current code creates all jpanels first. When i clicked a menu item, shows me jpanel created before.

I think it can be done with Class.forName method, but i couldn't figure it out. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the `new MyPersonalJPanel()` in the `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method. That way the panel would be created each time the user click on the menu.

Your code would then be:

```
// this function defines menu items and their listeners
public JMenuItem AddMenuItem(JMenu menu, String name) {
    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(name);
    menu.add(menuItem);

    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            SwitchPanel(new MyPersonalJPanel());
        }
    });

    return menuItem;
}
```

Comment: MyPersonalJPanel is different for every menu item. Do i have to code seperate listeners for every menu item? I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: You can also pass the Class<?> object for your panel as a AddMenuItem parameter, and then do Class.newInstance(). However it will often be considered as unsafe: if the constructor changes it will compile but fail at runtime. I would prefer passing the ActionListener instance as a parameter to method AddMenuItem.

Comment: I thought pass constructor instead of class but still a lot of effort for very little benefit. I will pass listeners, thanks for helping.